# How to get disconnected teeth and beard to move with rigged face?

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

So I'm trying to weight paint but can't seem to get my teeth and beard on the character to move with his head on two different bones, I have tried to move the head then weight paint it so that it gets moved into position as I paint but that doesn't work because it just stops getting closer to the head... so if someone could help using like team viewer or something that would help me a ton.

[image]
newest image:

[image: Failing]

Comment: Try to assign a jaw/teeth vertices with a weight value=1.000 to the head bone. It should follow the head then.

Comment: sorry im new haha so if i go into edit mode and highlight what i want to change the value too, then where would i go to find the vertex weights tab?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/some-vertices-dont-move-along-with-the-rig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to recreate the similiar issue as yours for you. As you can see below the *jaw* mesh doesn't follow the *head's* movement. It's because the jaw's *vertices* are not properly assigned to the *head* bone.
[image]

Select the *head bone* in *Pose Mode*, then select the mesh. In *Edit Mode* select all the vertices that belongs to jaw. Go to the *Mesh Data* header and in the ***Vertex Groups*** panel assign (press the ***Assign*** button) them with the *weight* of ***1.000*** to the *head bone*.
[image]

---

EDIT: I've weight painted the left side of your model. Unfortunatelly it wasn't symmetrical, so I couldn't mirror the weights to the right side of the rig. You'll have to do it manually.
Here's the .blend: [image]

Comment: ok so that sort of works now whenever i move the head it moves the beard and mouth with it but it lags behind it, like for example i move the head and they follow its just a little bit behind and it clips through the head, and on the other joint that i move it does not move with it can i assign it too multiple joints?

Comment: It looks like some head vertices are assigned to other bones, like neck bone etc. You have to remove them from that bone (e.g. select the neck bone in Pose Mode, then select all the head vertices in Edit Mode and press Remove button in Vertex Grops panel). TIP: When parenting the mesh to the armature (Ctrl+P) use a With Automatic Weights option. It will assign automatically proper vertex groups to the proper bones. Then correct some weights using Assign and Remove buttons.

Comment: i already did that it didnt solve anything here is a new photos of my weight failing:  ok it looks like that in the second photo

Comment: is there a way that i can hide everything i select in edit mode so that i can see only a select few items that i want then switch to weight mode on a joint??? Maby

Comment: or a way to group everything i want in edit mode so that when i am in weight mode i can weight everything i grouped really easy

Comment: also when i move the neck bone it rotates the hole head but if i rotate one of the other head bones it flattens the head....

Comment: Could you please post your .blend file via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? I'll try to look at your model and weight paint it for you, so the rig'll work as it should.

Comment: yup here it is: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1141" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1141/)                                                            password is:  "IReallywantthistoowork"            and your going to need the source plugin: http://steamreview.org/BlenderSourceTools/

Comment: @Jaydon Thanks for uploading the file. I'll take a look at it ASAP. Meanwhile take a look at this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21305/armature-moving-points-for-no-apparent-reason

Comment: so unfortunately that solution didn't work for both of the solutions he had :(

Comment: anything yet????

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting. I don't used to work in Easter :). The holidays are over, so I've found some time to do it. Though, because the model isn't symmetrical I haven't managed to mirror the weights to the bones on the right. Though I hope you'll get the idea how it works and paint them manually. Please see my edit and download the .blend. Also, check out this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/some-vertices-dont-move-along-with-the-rig

Comment: oh haha so sorry i totally space that it was Easter... whoops