# Problems when rigging; only some of the object moves with rig even when automatically weighted?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I have this character I am trying to rig. I created the rig, and did not apply automatic weight yet. I have his hair in a separate object, so I joined the character and his hair with Ctrl+J. I then added automatic weight to the armature, but some of his hair does not move with him.

How can I fix this? Ctrl+P Keep Offset gives a similar issue.

Here is the blender file:

(The normal blender upload site doesnt seem to be working... heres a Mediafire)

https://www.mediafire.com/?kab867zkkh6snb4

Comment: After joining the hair with a body (Ctrl+J) assign the hair vertex group to the head bone with the weight value of 1.000. Please see these related answers: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49388/how-to-get-disconnected-teeth-and-beard-to-move-with-rigged-face and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/some-vertices-dont-move-along-with-the-rig

Comment: You may also use a simplier method. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the hair, then a head bone and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*Set Parent to*-->***Bone***.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Quick question, is there a way to parent it to multiple objects? Like if he had a shirt, how do I make the shirt wrap around his arms and body without poking through a ton? :o

Comment: I guess parenting the cloth to the bone won't work. You'll have to copy to weights of the body to the shirt to follow the bone properly. If you'll have problems with it ask a separate question and I'll try to help :).